# Netapp files backup

Tags: azure

Could Netapp files include a feature comparable to blob soft delete, and is there a backup mechanism to prevent accidental deletions of files or volumes? I'm interested in learning about data protection and recovery options within Netapp, seeking a thorough understanding of available safeguards against data loss.

Hoping to know about the above information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Azure NetApp Files do not have support for soft delete and is under consideration for upcoming cycle. Stay tuned for announcement of features [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?query=Azure%20NetApp%20Files).

No soft delete available but see if this helps Understand [Azure NetApp Files backup | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-netapp-files/backup-introduction)

**Important**: The Azure NetApp Files backup feature is currently in preview. You need to submit a waitlist request for accessing the feature through the Azure NetApp Files Backup Public Preview page. Wait for an official confirmation email from the Azure NetApp Files team before using the Azure NetApp Files [backup](https://forms.office.com/pages/responsepage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR2Qj2eZL0mZPv1iKUrDGvc9UMkI3NUIxVkVEVkdJMko3WllQMVRNMTdEWSQlQCN0PWcu) feature.